# Proof and example of the formulas for $\sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\theta_i\right)$ and $\cos\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\theta_i\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Was reading the page on ["List of trigonometric identities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sines_and_cosines_of_sums_of_infinitely_many_angles) on Wikipedia and came across an identity for sines and cosines of sums of infinitely many angles whose sum converges absolutely towards a single value. The identities are as follows:

[image]

I can't for the life of me find a proof of these identities online nor are they cited from anywhere on the wikipedia page and where would this be useful could someone give a problem for this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin\left(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \theta_r \right) = Im\left(\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}e^{i\theta_r}\right)$$

Now we really just need to simplify this product using Euler's identity. We can write it down as $$P=Im\left(\prod_{r=1}^{\infty} \cos(\theta_r)+i\sin(\theta_r)\right)$$

Now since $\lim_{r \to \infty} \sin(\theta_r) =0$, we must use finitely many $\sin$ factors in each term and since $\lim_{r \to \infty} \cos(\theta_r) =1$, we may use infinitely many $\cos$ factors in a term.

When we write this product as a sum of factors, all imaginary terms within the product are those which have different $\sin$ multiplied with each other an odd number of times, since $i^{4k+2}=-1$. Further since $i^{4k+1}=i$ and $i^{4k+3}=-i$, for non-negative $k$ the terms which have $\sin$ factors $4k-1$ times will be negative.

So when we multiply the factors and write out the imaginary terms, it will appear as a sum of products of $\sin$ of an angle multiplied with $\cos$ of all other angles, taken one $\sin$ at a time, then three $\sin$, then five $\sin$ at a time, and so on, for all possible combinations of angles for the $\sin$ terms. In terms of product and sum notation, we can write this down as $$i\sum_{t \text{ odd}} (-1)^{[t \bmod 4 = 3]} \sum_{s \subset N, |s|=t} \left( \prod_{r \in s} \sin(\theta_r)\prod_{r\notin s}\cos(\theta_r)\right)$$

Here $[\ .\ ]$ stands for Iverson brackets. In essence, the first summation let's us choose how many $\sin$ factors each term should contain, $t$, and the second summation allows us to choose a combination of $t$ angles from the infinitely many angles to be used for the argument in the $\sin$. The sign associated with the number of $\sin$ terms is also appended.

Now $t=4k+3$ implies that $\frac{t-1}{2} = 2k+1$ which is an odd value and that means $(-1)^{[t \bmod 4 = 3]} = (-1)^{\frac{t-1}{2}}$. So we might as well replace the Iverson bracket with this.

The same follows for the $\cos$ expansion, where in order to find the $Re$ part you have to take each $\sin$ only an even number of terms, while noting that $i^{4k+1}=-1$ and $i^{4k}=1$ for non-negative $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Like most trigonometric inequalities, you can show it using that $e^{ix}=\cos (x) +i \sin (x)$.

In particular, expand both sides of $e^{i(\sum_j \theta_j)}=\prod_j e^{i\theta_j}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate